# Kendo Ui Editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

Please see the screen shot, the editor renders but there are no icons on the tool bar, I checked editor.png is in the default folder.

```
<textarea cols="25" rows="5" id="History" 
    style="width:420px"  name="History"  
    placeholder="this is a History field" ></textarea>

$("#History").kendoEditor({
        tools: [
            "bold",
            "italic",
            "underline",
            "strikethrough",
            "justifyLeft",
            "justifyCenter",
            "justifyRight",
            "justifyFull"
               ]
    });
```

And the screenshot is

[image]

Comment: Are you seeing any messages in your browser console?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are including the CSS file:

```
<link href="/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

and that you have a file called `sprites.png` in `/styles/Default`

Comment: css and png image is already there... I know its some kind of css conflict, I don't understand how to identify the clash.

Comment: Do you use firebug, chrome or some browser with development tools? Right-click on where the icon should be displayed, and check the HTML (class attribute) and CSS definitions for that element (the missing icon). As far as we are not able of reproducing it is hard to guess what is happening.